# MySQL Table Update Error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm almost sorry to ask this question but I'm drawing a complete blank. I'm getting the following error:

*"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE number='7'' at line 1"*

It seems whenever I try to use just an integer in the following code, I get the syntax error;

```
$go = mysql_query("UPDATE $db1 SET count='$t1c', WHERE number='$input2'") or die(mysql_error());
```

As you can see the page gets the value, that's not the issue.. it just doesn't seem to like the WHERE = 7 part. I've tried with and without the quote marks, I've tried changing that column in the table from a int to a varchar. Still get the same thing yet the code BEFORE this piece that runs:

```
$check1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db1 WHERE number='$input2'");
```

Run's absolutely fine. It finds the value where number equals $input2...

Can someone help me PLEASE? I'm drawing a complete blank here :/

Comment: No need the `,` character after `SET count='$t1c',` remove the coma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `,` in the query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $db1 SET count='$t1c' WHERE number='$input2'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma(,) which is placed before WHERE in UPDATE query

```
$go = mysql_query("UPDATE $db1 SET count='$t1c' WHERE number='$input2'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
`"UPDATE $db1 SET count='$t1c', WHERE number='$input2'"`
to
`"UPDATE $db1 SET count='$t1c' WHERE number='$input2'"`

The comma shouldn't be there (before WHERE) and is causing an error.

Answer (score -1):

number is a reserved word in mysql sql 
it is better not to name columns with that words or you need to backtick them in query

example:

```
`number`=3
```

[mysql reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)